# 'blender' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: command-line, windows

I can't get any blender commands to work in the windows command line. I have added to the PATH and changed the directory to where Blender is on my laptop but I just keep getting this error:

'blender' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I don't know what else to try, does anyone else know how to fix this?

Comment: It's hard to replicate without knowing *exactly* where and what you changed.

Comment: I haven't changed anything. I just want to be able to use the Blender command line arguments but every time it gives me the error where 'blender' isn't recognized. I've added the blender file path to my system PATH and have tried when my directory is changed to where Blender is saved but have had no luck :(

Comment: Show us your path editor and you blender installation folder

Comment: " I have added to the PATH and changed the directory to where Blender is on my laptop" sounds like a change to me, so...

Comment: Oh, I see sorry! I added the path of where my Blender is saved on my device to my system variables PATH. How can I show you? Sorry, it's my first time posting here.

Comment: Make screenshots, edit your original post and paste your screenshots in. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html

Comment: @L0Lock I like that link, so much. As people don't recognize print screen key in their keyboard in nowadays.